# repeat search in vim: count is off by one sometimes

Tags: search, count

I've happily used count prefixes on search commands in vim for probably a couple of decades, so I know they used to count correctly. `5n` was equivalent to `n` 5 times.

As of some recent version, `5n` is sometimes equivalent to `n` 5 times, and sometimes equivalent to `n` 6 times.

I can no longer type `5n`, see the cursor stay in the same place while the "search wrapped" message appears at the bottom of the screen, and know that there are 5 whatevers in the file. Which sounds really silly when I try to explain it, but it's apparently something I was doing subconsciously *all the time*, so the new version is driving me crazy.

What could be causing the search repeat count to behave inconsistently, and how can I fix it?

About my environment: The active options as reported by `:set` are

```
  autoindent          expandtab           ruler               ttymouse=xterm
  background=dark     fileformats=        shiftwidth=2        viminfo=
  backspace=1       nofsync               swapsync=           wrapmargin=3
  cpoptions=BceFs$t nojoinspaces        notextauto
noequalalways       noloadplugins         tildeop
noesckeys           nomore                ttyfast
  completeopt=preview
  formatoptions=tcroq2b
  path=.,/usr/include,,,/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
  printoptions=paper:letter
  runtimepath=~/.vim,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/
vim80,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,~/.vim/after
  suffixes=.bak,~,.swp,.o,.info,.aux,.log,.dvi,.bbl,.blg,.brf,.cb,.ind,.idx,.ilg
,.inx,.out,.toc
```

Some of those settings come from the Debian packaging. The rest are my preferences. I don't do scripting, plugins, or any other fancy stuff.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of a pattern which shows this issue?  `n` does have logic to repeat count+1 times (see `:h n`) but the circumstances in which it happens is somewhat rare https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/cOjJrIk3pZg .  Note that this change was made in early 2015.

Comment: A couple of the `cpoptions` flags (e.g. 'c') can change search fairly dramatically in some cases. Is it possible those flags changed recently? (Suggestion from Mass seems more relevant but leave no stone unturned...)

Comment: Actually not rare at all.. (demonstrated by guillem's answer)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like in the current version of `vim` the `n` command is guaranteed to move the cursor, unless there is exactly *one* match on the file.

However, the search command `/` will behave as you are used to. Consider a file with  these contents:

```
word
word
```

Let's imagine that the cursor is at the beginning of the file. Searching for "word" will place the cursor at the beginning of line 2. Pressing `2n` the cursor will move to the first line, triggering the "search wrapped" message. Now the cursor is in the first line, and if you press `2/<CR>`, it will stay on the first line, also triggering the "search wrapped" message.

#### Workaround

You can remap `n` to restore the desired behavior:

```
nmap n /<CR>
```

Comment: It is even more apparent if you have 5 lines containing words and press `5n`, it will jump 6 times.  This seems like a bug, or at least an unintended consequence (although to be fair, it is indeed documented)..